# Laravel php artisan shows another popup window, is this a bug?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

When write php artisan, i recive new command line, it's close quick, i not see result.

Picture
[image: Result when write php artisan]

Comment: More details please. Where are you running your command? What directory. How did you install php. What os etc.

Comment: Hi Wahyu Kristianto, i used wamp server run php.
I write php arisan in my project, but it not show in command

Comment: This is detail info
https://imgur.com/a/TnShrUB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the directory that has php.exe in you WAMP installation, into your PATH (environment variables).

**Windows 10 and Windows 8**

1. In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
2. Click the Advanced system settings link.
3. Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
4. In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.
5. reboot system and Reopen orginal Command prompt window with type cmd in RUN menu.
6. place in laravel app folder in Command prompt window then run php artisan.

"php artisan" command not work out of the laravel folder.

Comment: Hi nekooee, thanks you support.
I try fix solution with anwesr is you, but not work :(
Link picture: https://prnt.sc/lty66w

Comment: I check your gif and php artisan wordked fine but open in new window and after process complete, closed. for test open the orginal windows cmd from RUN menu and go to app folder then type "php artisan --verssion". only open app folder with orginal windows cmd.